# Is there some tag that provides the functions of <p> without adding line breaks?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I ask this because I need 1 line of text that has left aligned text and right aligned text on the same line without creating blank space above or below it. For example:

```
Left aligned                                                      right aligned
```

with no line breaks above and below it.  The only solutions I've seen to this problem include the `<p>` tag or `<div>` tag that create line breaks.

Comment: Both flex box and floats will achieve this kind of results

Comment: As will `display: inline-block` applied to two similar elements

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "blank space above or below it" when contrasted with the assertion in the title that you want preserve "the functions of <p>".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want two pieces of text on the same line but on opposite sides. To do this, you could use the CSS `float` property:

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpvt2frL/

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 450px;
}
.container div {
  position: inline-block;
}
.left-span {
  float: left;
}
.right-span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<section class='container'>
  <div class='left-span'>Left text on a line...</div>
  <div class='right-span'>...right text on the same line!</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:flex` and `justify-content: space-between` on the parent element (usually the container) to achieve this.

```css
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #eee;
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <span>left-aligned</span>
  <span>right-aligned</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alignment and floating elements are not quite the same thing, but this will render the basic behavior you're looking for:

```
<p style="float: left;">Left aligned</p>
<p style="float: right;">right aligned</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: inline-block`:

```css
#left,
#right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
#left {
  text-align: left;
}
#right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:400px;border:1px solid black">
  <div id="left">Align left</div><!--
  --><div id="right">Align right</div>
</div>
```

This also avoids having to clear floats afterwards.